# Reading specific files in a directory in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to list files in a directory

```
files = list.files("folder/", pattern="csv")
```

For example, 
if the output is

```
a.csv
b.csv
c.csv
```

Now, I would like to select only specific files from the folder by using `list` below as a filter.
The name of the files, without extension, is stored in a list.

```
list <- list("a", "b")
```

I would like to store only a.csv and b.csv in `files`

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a regex pattern using your list of filenames:

```
lst <- list("a", "b")
pat <- paste0("\\b(", paste(lst, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
files = list.files("folder/", pattern="csv")
files.keep <- grep(pat, files, value=TRUE)
files.keep

[1] "a.csv" "b.csv"
```

This assumes that you would be using filenames which have word boundaries on both sides.  This works with the above data, since the name used is from the start, and also the extension on the right starts with dot.